# Cassandra build fails with "Unsupported JDK version used 1.8" error

Tags: java, build, java-8, cassandra

I'm trying to compile cassandra from source on a x86 linux machine. I cloned the github repo of cassandra and trying to build using java8. The error says
`home/ubuntu/opensource/cassandra/build.xml:215: Unsupported JDK version used: 1.8`

In the documentation it says it supports both java8 and java11. Is there anything I should do prior to compiling? The same repository compiles with java11. I'm curious why java8 isn't compiling it.
My java spec is: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_392-8u392-ga-1~22.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: "In the documentation it says it supports both java8 and java11".  No, it doesn't

Comment: Which documentation says that?  Please provide a link to the documentation that says that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading the documentation correctly or reading the wrong documentation.  Plainly from the current README in the github repo

https://github.com/apache/cassandra

> Requirements
>
> Java: see supported versions in build.xml (search for property "java.supported").

which has

cassandra/build.xml:

`<property name="java.supported" value="11,17" />`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I have read the documentation from https://cassandra.apache.org/_/development/ide.html and got compelled to use java 11. Now it makes sense to me. Appreciate the response!